# PhantomJS Mocktail Map Error

Tags: phantomjs, babeljs

Trying to run my jasmine tests, writeen in ES2015 via Babel, in phantomjs via karma-phantomjs; getting this issue--

```
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Mac OS X 0.0.0) ERROR                                                                                                                                  
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Map                                                                                                                              
at /var/folders/mf/n6g7nwd119vbmkg80d0yvm380000gn/T/19f6091b4a350b18bbe890201c914b34.browserify:26852 <- node_modules/mocktail/dist/mocktail.js:41:0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ran `npm install --save-dev babel-polyfill`, modified my setup.js mocktail file like so:

```
import 'babel-polyfill';
import {env, ENV} from 'mocktail';
env(ENV.TESTING);
```